# Decorator Causing All Functions to Return True

Tags: python

In an attempt to debug an online permissions system I was having problems with, I've created a couple of classes and functions designed to replicate the issue offline. Unfortunately, I'm having a problem, in which turning a function into a decorator completely changes the results of a decorated function.

My code is as follows, I've kept it as basic as possible, to illustrate my point.

1. Setting up User class:

   ```
   class User(object):

       def __init__(self, forename=None, surname=None, logged_in=True, exists=True, poop=False, admin=False):
           self.forename = forename
           self.surname = surname
           self.logged_in = logged_in
           self.exists = exists
           self.poop = poop
           self.admin = admin

       def __repr__(self):
           return f'User: {self.forename} {self.surname}.'

   user1 = User('Paddy', 'McHugh', True, True, False, True)
   user2 = User('Rodney', 'Donger', False, False, True, False)
   user3 = User('Bob', 'Dangler', True, True, True, True)
   ```
2. Creating functions to test against a user:

   ```
   def user_just_is(user):
       return user.exists


   def user_is_poop(user):
       return user.poop


   def user_is_admin(user):
       return user.admin
   ```
3. Testing those functions against the chosen user with a **regular** function:

   ```
   class Permissions2(object):

       def __init__(self):
           pass

       def requires(self, *args):
           user = user2

           if not user.logged_in:
               print('You\'re not logged in, please log in.')
               return

           if not all(i(user) for i in args):
               print('Not all of the conditions were met.')
           else:
               print('All of the conditions were met.')


   Permissions2().requires(user_just_is, user_is_poop, user_is_admin)
   ```
4. Testing those functions against the chosen user with a **decorator** function:

   ```
   class Permissions(object):

       def __init__(self):
           pass

       def requires(self, *args):
           user = user2

           def decorator(func):
               @wraps(func)
               def allower(*args, **kwargs):
                   if not user.logged_in:
                       print('You\'re not logged in, please log in.')
                       return


                   if not all(i(user) for i in args):
                       print('Not all of the conditions were met.')
                       return

                   return func(*args, **kwargs)

               return allower

           return decorator


   @Permissions.requires(user_just_is, user_is_poop, user_is_admin)
   def print_stuff():
       print('All of the conditions were met.')

   print_stuff()
   ```

I'd expect the outcome of both the regular and decorator function to be the same. That if User.logged_in == False, then it would print: `'You're not logged in, please log in.'`. That if all the Boolean variables were True, it would print: `'All of the conditions were met.'`. That if any of the conditions were False, it would print: `'Not all of the conditions were met.'`.

The decorator function still returns the `'You're not logged in, please log in'`, but if User.logged_if == True, then the other Booleans don't matter, it always returns True to the `all()` function and print `'All of the conditions were met.'`.

What is it about putting it in a decorator that means `all()` seems to return True to all of the tested functions?

Comment: fwiw, `print` returns `None`

Comment: Why do you keep `return`ing the result of `print` calls? That will always return `None`

Comment: @DeepSpace @juanpa.arrivillaga Apologies, that was just a leftover from when I was testing if that made a difference. Edited now. I do want to return `None`, however, to prevent the decorated function from returning, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `args` parameter for your `allower` function shadows the `args` parameter of `requires`, so when you iterate over `args` here:

```
if not all(i(user) for i in args):
```

you are not iterating through the list of functions passed in to `requires` as `args` anymore, but rather the `args` passed to the decorated function. You should rename the parameter to avoid the naming conflict.

Moreover, you're defining `Permissions.requires` as an instance method so its first parameter is `self`, the object that the method is bound to, so when you call:

```
@Permissions.requires(user_just_is, user_is_poop, user_is_admin)
```

`user_just_is` is passed as `self`, rather than becoming part of `args`. Since `requires` does not actually make use of `self`, it should be defined as a static method instead.

So with the above issues fixed, your `Permissions` class should look like:

```
class Permissions(object):
    @staticmethod
    def requires(*conditions):
        user = user2

        def decorator(func):
            @wraps(func)
            def allower(*args, **kwargs):
                if not user.logged_in:
                    return print('You\'re not logged in, please log in.')

                if not all(i(user) for i in conditions):
                    return print('Not all of the conditions were met.')

                return func(*args, **kwargs)

            return allower

        return decorator
```

Comment: It should just be defined outside the class

Comment: Static methods can always be defined outside the class, but are usually defined as static methods just to group similarly-purposed functions together for better readability. So if the OP does have other permission-related decorators not shown here then it can make sense to keep `requires` as a static method of the `Permissions` class.

Comment: The natural way to namespace a bunch of functions that don't require shared state is to *just use a module*. At the end, though, it is a matter of taste.

Comment: @blhsing you absolute hero, that's done the trick! Thanks very much!